# CentOs 6.5 final and Datastax Enterprise 4

Tags: cassandra, centos, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have previously setup cassandra using the datastax community edition and have tried to move to Enterprise 4.

I've tried installing via the optscenter web interface and had it 'Start Errored: Timed out waiting for Cassandra to start.' on all 4 nodes.

I've also tried the manual approach outlined on the site.  In this case just as the other it launches the dse service 'successfully'.  Output.log and system.logs show the classpath as the last entry and no errors in them at all.

```
Java: Jre-1.7.0_51
Os: centos 6.5 Final
Vagrant box: https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion would be that your VM does not have enough memory. If physical addressable memory is smaller than the MAX_HEAP_SIZE configured in resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh jna will go bonkers. You want to have at least 4GB of memory, or change the value in cassandra-env.sh.

Comment: Increased the memory to 4 gigs and it worked without the previous issues.